# Como pegar o CSS que foi defido em outra página?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Olá, sou novo em desenvolvimento front-end, desculpa se a minha pergunta é meio tosca, mas o que eu gostaria de saber é se é possível pegar o arquivo de CSS que foi definido em uma página e usa esse mesmo CSS nas demais. Esse projeto utiliza Velocity, portanto estava pensando em algo do tipo:

Um arquivo chamado style.vm por exemplo

```
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
       #IF(cliente == 1)
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cliente1.css">
       #ELSE IF (cliente == 2)
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cliente2.css">
       #ELSE IF (cliente == 3)
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cliente3.css">
       #ELSE IF (cliente == 4)
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cliente4.css">
       .
       .
       .
       #END
   <HEAD>
</HTML>
```

e nos outros .VMs e .JSPs pegar o css que foi definido nesse arquivo, pois não queria copiar todos esses IFs para cada arquivo do projeto.
Eu tenho a opção de usar JQuery caso seja necessário, pois todas as páginas desse projeto importam JQuery.

Comment: A resposta do Daniel Omine respondeu a sua dúvida? Se sim, marque a reposta dele como a solução. Saiba como no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

Poderia fazer do seguinte modo

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cliente[$cliente].css">
```

Só isso basta, não precisaria da condicional if.

obs: no lugar de `[$cliente]`, coloque a variável `cliente` do "velocity"

Answer (score -1):

Geralmente quando um cliente esta logado no sistema ele pega essas informações na session, o que você poderia fazer era definir diferentes temas para o sistemas, e atribuir um tema que chamaria o arquivo css. Para isso acho que você deveria utilizar de alguma linguagem para o back-end da aplicação caso não use.

Armazenando assim os dados em um banco de dados você poderia imprimir no link do estilo o tema do usuário que esta acessando.